# white space between container after I add javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i find this piece of javascript code online to solve text scalable problem. 
view-source:http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/dynamicTextSize.html
After I add this on my code. there are some white space between my containers which are all images. The white space only come out after i add script, it will disappear if i delete it. 
Anyone knows how to remove this white space?

Note: there are no space between my div tag.

```
.page1{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

first_page_image{
width:100%;
}

.page1_text{
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 4%;
    margin-left:14%;
}
}
page2{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

.second_page_image{
width:100%;
}

page2_text{
position:absolute;
margin-left:14%;
}
```

page1 and page2 are containers. image and text are all in the container

Comment: Please try to elaborate a bit. It is very difficult to help you with so little info. A jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cT4AT/

Comment: I add 2 images, and text on the image. but there are white space between image which i don't know how to remove it

Comment: The code for reproducing the issue should be in the question; not through a third party link (either JSFiddle or that site).

Comment: Done, I added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then try to add a css property:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Image by default is inline element so this style will help to remove whitespace below image.

Answer (score 0):

That's because images by default are displayed inline, vertically aligned with text. You can solved this in two ways:

Either set display:block on your images, or set vertical-align:top, if you wish to keep images displayed inline.